# Android signup with Firebase working but addition information doesn't save to real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Android signup with Firebase working but addition information doesn't save to real time database.  I am try to signup user with Firebase. I have done every as the docs told me to do and everything seems fine. The problem is the users get register but the additional information of the users don't save in the real time database and no error or log is show.
//user information

```
User user;
            if (whichUser == "Student") {
                user = new User(userName, userContact, "student");
            } else {
                user = new User(userName, userContact, "hostelers");
            }
           

           //signup with email and password
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                              //save the user infromation to db
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                                        if (task1.isSuccessful()) {
                                            mDialog.dismiss();
                                            register.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            Toast.makeText(this, "User registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        } else {
                                            mDialog.dismiss();
                                            register.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            Toast.makeText(this, "" + task1.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                        } else {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            register.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(this, "" + task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
        });

[Null Database the addition information is not saved][1]
[The user is registered][2]
[Firebase dependency][3]
[Sign up implementation][4]

 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImEhp.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy3MB.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDetk.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1WTf.png
```

Comment: Is any of the Toast messages display something?

Comment: No, the toast is not displaying anything

Comment: Is your onComplete or onFailure even triggered? What is the location of your database?

Comment: Which onComplete? The first one or the second one?

Comment: Sry, not even onComplete is triggered now

Comment: What is the location of your database?

Comment: First onComplete is not triggred

Comment: I dont know how to look for location of database

Comment: In your Firebase Console, check the settings.

Comment: The location of db is asia-east2

Comment: In that case, please check the duplicate.

Comment: how can be there duplicates if any of the data is not getting inserted into the db

Comment: Have you tried to pass "asia-east2" to your getInstance call?

Comment: Thanks, it worked by passing the url of db to getInstance

Comment: Good to hear that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the node `Users`->`Uid` for which you are trying to get the reference.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
```